# why does weak-* convergence implies weak convergence when X is reflexive ?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

how can you prove that weak-* convergence implies weak convergence when $X$ is reflexive ?

For a sequence $l_k\in X^*$ let $l_k \overset{*}{\rightharpoonup} l$. This means $l_k(x)\rightarrow l(x)\forall x\in X$. Since $X$ is reflexive the embedding $J:X\rightarrow X^{**}$ is surjective. How do you show that  $\lambda_x(l_k)\rightarrow\lambda_x(l)$ for all $\lambda_x\in X^{**}$
More precisely: how do you use the surjectivity of J ?

Comment: Write $\lambda_x = J(x)$. By definition of $J$, what is $J(x)(l_k)$?

Comment: $J(x)(l_k)=\lambda_x(l_k)=l_k(x)$ is that correct ?

Comment: Yes. Do you see how to use the surjectivity of $J$ now?

Comment: But I've could say that $\lambda_x(l_k)=l_k(x)$ without the surjectivity

Comment: But the point is that _every_ $\xi \in X^{\ast\ast}$ is of the form $J(x)$ for some $x\in X$.

Comment: So: $J(x)(l_k)=l_k(x)$ no matter what happens. But because $J$ is surjective we can say $\lambda_x(l_k)=l_k(x)$ ,is that correct ?

Comment: @ThomasMuller I think your problem is that already the notation $\lambda_x\in X^{**}$ suggests that you are in a reflexive setting. In general you have $\lambda\in X^{**}$ but you know there is $x\in X$ s.t. $\lambda=\lambda_x$ since $X$ is reflexive.

Comment: Because $J$ is surjective, we can say that $\lambda(l_k) \to \lambda(l)$ for _all_ $\lambda \in X^{\ast\ast}$, for they are all of the form $J(x)$.